# PATH variable for newly installed executable files

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am installing a series of programs for bioinformatics purposes; I am installing the folders of these packages in `/usr/local/lib/` and creating soft links to the executable files in `/usr/bin/` so I am expecting to have them visible in the environment. But when I type the executables in the terminal, the commands are not recognized, so they are not in the environment.

I also modified the `/home/userName/.bashrc` with the line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/
```

but still no luck; for instance for the `bowtie2` program, contained in the `/usr/local/lib/Bowtie` folder, I wrote:

```
/usr/local/lib/Bowtie$ bowtie2 --version
The program 'bowtie2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt-get install bowtie2
```

same thing when I open the terminal in default folder `name@userName:~$`.
I have not really clear how to modify this PATH environment; on the help online seems simple, but I can't make it work.

How can I modify the environment in a way that the newly added executables could be accessible globally?

Comment: Add the outputs of `echo $PATH` and `ls -la /usr/bin/ | grep bowtie`. Also, how did you install those programs and where did you get them from? If an application is available through the official Ubuntu repositories (as e.g. `bowtie2` seems to be), you should install it from there and not manually.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you try to run an executable whose directory you are in, you have to add ./ to the command, for example:

```
user@USER-PC:/usr/local/lib/Bowtie$ ./bowtie2
```

So bash (I suppose you're using bash, but many shells will work like this) will look for the executable in the current directory, not in PATH.
To add `/usr/local/lib/Bowtie` to PATH, just edit `~/.bashrc` and add `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/Bowtie`. This way bash will look for `bowtie2` in this directory.

If you created a link to bowtie2 inside `/usr/bin` and bash does not recognize it then probably `bowtie2` is not marked as executable. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/lib/Bowtie/bowtie2
```

and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I recreated the symlinks to the executable (which are marked as such) and now looks how it is working fine, so if I open the general terminal (name@userName:~$) and type bowtie2 the command is recognized. These softwares I am installing are not available from the software centre (but I can install bowtie with sudo apt get) and I need a common strategy for all. Tx